Responsive buttons using guidelines and constraynt layout in kotlin android studio
Hi I am doing kotlin calculator app for university homework and i had buttons being placed like this
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.832"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.22" />

Now my teacher told me that i have to use guidelines for this so i made one vertical and one horizontal but i have problems doing another buttons cause i want them to relate to the one near them so for example in code below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdvancedCalcActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ac"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_color"
        android:text="AC"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.22"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

i want another button lets call it "+" to be realted to AC button not using DPI but using values like the first code i provided so it can be fully responsive on all devices and in horizontal and landscape mode
